# Trying to convert js string to NSDateFormatter

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

JS Date type is

```
11-22-2013 00:00:00
```

And I want to convert it to

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

but getting nil in `myConvertedDate` if I do

```
  NSDate *myConvertedDate = [df dateFromString:myDate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format string does not match date.  Did you mean

```
MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: @Ecko123 did the change work?  If so you should accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myConvertedDate = [df dateFromString:myDate];
```

As your date format is 11-22-2013 00:00:00 (MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss)